VS Code Sending Over 100 lines of Python to Interpreter
In VS Code every time I send more python code than is on my editor screen to the interpreter with shift + enter it freezes up with a "PTY disconnection"
I would like to highlight my entire .py file and "shift + enter" it to the interpreter.
I restarted my computer.
I have installed several different versions of VS Code but I cannot get it to work.
I installed/re-installed the extensions
How can I do this?

Rolling back the extension to v14.1 will mitigate the issue before there is any fix regarding this.

I've been having this same issue recently and it's driving me mad.
macOS Sequoia Version 15.1
python 3.9.6 64bit
vscode insiders 1.96.0-insider (Universal)
Extensions:
Python (microsoft) - rolled back to 2024.14.0
Pylance
Python debugger
github copilot
github copilot chat
Read countless threads trying to find others with the same issue, trying all recommended solutions but no luck.

increasing buffer settings
different installations of vscode / clean re-installs
rolled back python extension
reinstalled all extensions
changed / removed overlapping keyboard shortcuts
tried running selection in virtual environments
tried installing most recent python version as different interpreter

Your issue sounds identical to mine, running any more than a few selected lines of code at a time results in the output to terminal freezing up while executing the code, only running a few lines before getting stuck/frozen halfway through running a random line (depending on where I start the selection from).
It seems as though the code WILL run if I go line by line but in a file with 100+ lines this is not ideal.
This functionality was working fine before and something has broken it but I cannot for the life of me figure out what.
The only other major change to my computer recently was upgrading the OS to Sequoia, so i will likely try that next but was avoiding having to revert OS.
example of code stopping halfway through line selection
